# Scope of C++ ABI chages

Tags: c++, gcc, abi, internals

I have following symbols defined in C++ static library:

```
struct P
{
    int a;
#ifdef D1
    int b;
#endif
};

class IInterface
{
public:
    virtual void bad(int, P) = 0;
    virtual void good(int, std::string) = 0;
};
```

And I have executable that links said static library. IInterface implementation resides in my executable and static library uses my implementation through IInterface. Problem is D1 was defined differently in static library and in executable. I want to grasp the scope of this problem. I guess calling bad() is bad idea. But is it safe to call good()?
Let's say its Linux environment and GCC was used. Where can I read more about these internals? Is it ELF format specs?

ABI change in question is the size change of P. All the rest is exactly the same for library and executable.

Comment: If `std::string` is incompatible, you may see undefined reference complained by linker. Eg: one compiled with gcc 4.9 below and another compiled with gcc 5.1 above. See [Dual-Abi](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html)